# How to remove duplicate elements from a c++ Bidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

When creating and duplicating the matrix, it writes it the way I want, my question is how can I eliminate the duplicate elements of matrix1 because I need it to only show me the values of the matrix without showing the duplicates. It would be more or less as follows.

enter number of rows: 3.

enter number of columns: 4.

Original Array:.

3 7 14 2.

6 2 3 15.

10 8 11 6.

Result Array:
3.

7.

14.

2.

6.

15.

10.

8.

11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
  int f = 0;
  int c = 0;
  cout<<"Ingresar numero de filas: ";
  cin>>f;
  cout<<"Ingresar numero de columnas: ";
  cin>>c;
  int matriz[f][c];
  int matriz1[f][c];

  srand(time(0));
  for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ )
      for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ )
         matriz[i][j] = 1 + rand()% 15;

  cout<< "Arreglo Original"<< endl;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ ){
       for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ ){
           cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" "; }
       cout<< endl;
}


cout<< "Arreglo resultante "<<endl;
for (int i = 0 ; i < f; i++ ){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < c ; j++ ){
        matriz1[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
    cout<< matriz1[i][j]<<endl;}

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "without showing duplicates" mean? The shown code appears to print the resulting matrix one value per line. If so, why does the input have to be stored in a any kind of a 2D array in the first place? Storing it in a single vector (and the shown 2d matrix is not even valid, standard C++ in the first place, but non-standard C++), then using `std::sort` with `std::unique` will do all the work for you. This shouldn't take more than two or three lines of code, after entering all the input.

Comment: You can't remove an element from an array. The best you can do is write something over it.

Comment: So you're just trying to eliminate the duplicate elements in the array? If that's the case, create a counting array that is the size of the `(row x columns) - 1` and as you add each value to the array, check to see if the value at `arr[matrix[i][j]] > 1`. If it is, change the value in the matrix to a non-usable number (negative or something), decrement the value at `arr[matrix[i][j]]`, and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> example{
        { 3, 7, 14, 2 },
        { 6, 2, 3, 15 },
        { 10, 8, 11, 6 }
    };
    int const max = 15; // while reading example find out max
    auto is_avail = std::make_unique<std::bitset<max + 1>>();
    std::vector<int> ans;
    for (auto const& v : example) {
        for (auto const e : v) {
            if (!is_avail->test(e)) {
                ans.emplace_back(e);
                is_avail->set(e, true);
            }
        }
    }
    std::copy(ans.cbegin(), ans.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

In case you want ans to be 2D too replace the code following the line

```
auto is_avail = std::make_unique<std::bitset<max + 1>>();
```

with

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> ans{ example };
    for (auto& v : ans) {
        for (auto& e : v) {
            if (!is_avail->test(e)) {
                is_avail->set(e, true);
            }
            else {
                e = -1; // error state
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto const& v : ans) {
        for (auto const e : v) {
            if (e != -1) {
                std::cout << std::setw(2) << e;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << std::setw(2) << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

and don't forget to

```
#include <iomanip>
```

for std::setw.